# Recursive function calls - generate permutations and backtracking

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking

I have a vector of strings, all of the same size.
I have to build as a solution a list of strings that fulfill some conditions.

The pseudo code algorithm would be something like this:

```
backtrack(N)
if solution_valid()
    print solution
else
    for each word in vector
        if(possible candidate)
           backtrack(N+1)
```

I get lost in how to actually write the code.

I do not understand how to save current solutions, what kind of parameters to pass to the function...

Here is something I have though I think it's completely wrong:

```
int backtrack(vector<string> &dictionary, vector<string> &solution, int current_row)
{
cout << "current row: "<< current_row <<  " of: " << rows << endl;
if(current_row == rows /*&& square_completed(solution)*/)
{
    vector<string>::iterator word;
    for(word = solution.begin(); word != solution.end(); ++word)
    {
        cout << *word << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}

vector<string>::iterator word;
for(word = dictionary.begin(); word != dictionary.end(); ++word)
{
    backtrack(dictionary,solution,current_row+1);
    solution.push_back(*word);


}

return 1;
```

}

problem is that solution keeps growing without control. 
Could you tell me how to deal with it? and do a proper backtracking?

Comment: This is better... `for(word = dictionary.begin(); word < dictionary.end(); ++word)`

Comment: @muntoo: Why would that be better?

Comment: muntoo thanks, but I'm trying to solve the conceptual problem. We can fix syntax later on :-)

Comment: @sth Well, maybe not in this case, but still...

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you modify `dictionary` while iterating over it. Modifying a vector invalidates iterators of that vector, so `word` is no longer valid when you use it the next time. This might crash or otherwise fail. But the `erase` function returns a new valid iterator, you can use that to continue iterating.

Also you basically erase all elements from `dictionary` in the backtrack function and quite fast there will be no element left in `dictionary`. Probably you want to re-add the erased elements after the recursive call returns?

Comment: indeed that is a mistake, I put it there for trying to solve some problems I couldn't solve. I would need to understand: I initialize the solution vector in the main before calling the recursive function right? then how can I correctly go on?

Comment: I modified the original source code to elimiante those weird calls. THere is still the problem on how to use the solution vectors and when to delete it